# Change File.Copy default buffer size.

Tags: c#, copy, buffer, system.io.file

I'm looking into ways to possibly improve file transfer speeds to a network drive. I'm currently using the standard File.Copy. Does anyone know the default buffer size for File.Copy and if it's possible to change it?

Comment: N/A - it doesn't do it that way - it asks the OS to copy it - [here's windows](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/FileSystem.Windows.cs#L19), and [here's *nix](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/FileSystem.Unix.cs#L28); what the OS chooses to do is up to it.

Comment: You might want to use different tools like _robocopy_ and _TeraCopy_ which are somewhat faster or offer extra features

Answer (score 3):

Given that `File.Copy` uses Window's copy functions, as you can see in the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,168):

```
internal const String KERNEL32 = "kernel32.dll";

[DllImport(KERNEL32, SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto, BestFitMapping=false)]
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.Machine)]
internal static extern bool CopyFile(...)

...
bool r = Win32Native.CopyFile(fullSourceFileName, fullDestFileName, !overwrite);
```

There's not a lot (in fact, nothing) you can do to optimize this.